# Example of contraction mapping

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Please give me some examples of contraction mapping on $(C[0,1]), \lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert_\infty)$ and $(C[0,1],\lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert_1) $.

Note that : 1.  $\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert_\infty = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)$  and $\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert_1 = \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert dx $.

2. $C[0,1]$ is a space of all continuous function on $[0,1]$
3. Let $T$ be a function from $(X,\lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert)$ into itself. We call  $T$ a contraction map if there exists $0<k<1$ such that $\lvert \lvert T(x) - T(y) \rvert \rvert \leq k \lvert \lvert x-y \rvert \rvert$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Answer (score 4):

A very important one: $$\Phi: \mathcal C([a,b],\Bbb R)\to \Bbb R $$

defined by $$\Phi(v)(t) = x_0 + \int_0^tF(v(s))\, ds$$

where $F:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is  Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Does $\Phi$ have a special name? I think I have seen it in nonlinear systems.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple and obvious example:
$$f\longmapsto kf.$$